# Virtual Earth VEShapeLayer Will Not Render

Tags: javascript, web-applications, virtual-earth, bing

The goal: Allow user to turn on and off different layers of data; and to dynamically pull the data for the current extent from a database on map move event.

This works fine and good if you hard code your VEShapeLayers as done [here](http://krkinnan.members.winisp.net/samples/v5/veshapes/veshapelayersample1.html).

My list of layers is coming from a database, I have everything working the way I want except that when I add shapes to my VEShapeLayer none are rendered on my map. Calling VEShapeLayer.GetShapeCount() returns the expected number... so the layer has the data..

Here are the important bits of the code:

```
var assets = [];
if (WebServiceResult.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < WebServiceResult.length; i++) {
        var ix = FindLayerIndex(WebServiceResult[0].AssetMapLayer);
        var velatlong = new VELatLong();
        velatlong.Latitude = WebServiceResult[i].Latitude;
        velatlong.Longitude = WebServiceResult[i].Longitude;
        newShape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, velatlong);
        assets.push(newShape);
    }
    // ix is defined above and is vaild and correct
    map.GetShapeLayerByIndex(ix).AddShape(assets);
}
// a call here to map.GetShapeLayerByIndex(ix).GetShapeCount()     
// returns the expected number of shapes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb; I had not added the stylesheet to my page's header, and my custom icon was rendering transparent as a result of the stylesheet not being available.